# Align form controls with nested object

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular

```
[{
    "customer name": "customerA",
    "invoice": [{
        "invoicename": "invoice1",
        "invoiceid": 123
    }, {
        "invoicename": "invoice2",
        "invoiceid": 123
    }]
}, {
    "customer name": "customerB",
    "invoice": [{
        "invoicename": "invoice1",
        "invoiceid": 123
    }, {
        "invoicename": "invoice2",
        "invoiceid": 123
    }]
}, {
    "customer name": "customerC",
    "invoice": [{
        "invoicename": "invoice1",
        "invoiced": 123
    }]
}]
```

I would like to create the dynamic form input controls in the below format along with form input validation using angular1.4.

Invoice object gets changed dynamically (either it has one or two invoice)

```
Row1
CustomerA invoicenametextbox invoicenametextbox  invoiceidtextbox invoiceidtextbox 

Row2
CustomerB invoicenametextbox invoicenametextbox  invoiceidtextbox invoiceidtextbox 

Row3
CustomerC invoicenametextbox emptyspace  invoiceidtextbox emptyspace
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried with ng-repeat inside ng-repeat .I am not able to align the text box dynamically with grouping invoicename and invoiceid as separate column

Comment: As it has either one or two invoice, why don't you use one `ng-repeat` and use `ng-switch` to determine when to show invoice or empty space?

Comment: Is this angular or angularjs? Please tag your question accordingly.